# Fast bootup, but slow login from GDM prompt to desktop

Tags: boot, gnome, login, login-screen, gdm

**Specs**

- Ubuntu version: 20.10 (groovy)
- Storage: SATA SSD
- RAM: 8 GB DDR3
- CPU: AMD A8-4500M APU
- GPU: AMD Radeon HD 7640G

**Problem**

Bootup is quite fast at 14 seconds as reported by `systemd-analyze`. But the time it takes to go from entering password from GDM prompt to desktop is quite high at 7 seconds (using Wayland display server). The default X11 display server was taking even longer at close to 10 seconds.

This is a fresh installation, AMD clock boost is enabled and active, `ondemand` governor. The default open source `radeon` graphics driver is loaded.

The below errors are logged whenever I *bootup and login* **or** *logout and then login*.

```
Apr  2 19:26:38 laptop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2466]: Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
Apr  2 19:26:50 laptop systemd[3224]: Not generating service for XDG autostart app-gnome\x2dsoftware\x2dservice-autostart.service, error parsing Exec= line: No such file or directory
Apr  2 19:26:50 laptop systemd[3224]: Not generating service for XDG autostart app-nautilus\x2dautostart-autostart.service, error parsing Exec= line: No such file or directory
Apr  2 19:26:51 laptop gnome-session[3368]: gnome-session-binary[3368]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 3384: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 3384 does not exist.
Apr  2 19:26:51 laptop gnome-session-binary[3368]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 3384: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 3384 does not exist.
Apr  2 19:26:51 laptop gnome-session[3368]: gnome-session-binary[3368]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 3387: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 3387 does not exist.
Apr  2 19:26:51 laptop gnome-session-binary[3368]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 3387: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 3387 does not exist.
Apr  2 19:26:54 laptop gnome-session[3368]: gnome-session-binary[3368]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 3518: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 3518 does not exist.
Apr  2 19:26:54 laptop gnome-session-binary[3368]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 3518: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 3518 does not exist.
Apr  2 19:26:54 laptop at-spi2-registr[3489]: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: Unable to register client
Apr  2 19:26:54 laptop gnome-session[3368]: gnome-session-binary[3368]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 3551: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 3551 does not exist.
Apr  2 19:26:54 laptop gnome-session-binary[3368]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 3551: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 3551 does not exist.
Apr  2 19:26:54 laptop gnome-session[3368]: gnome-session-binary[3368]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 3556: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 3556 does not exist.
Apr  2 19:26:54 laptop gnome-session-binary[3368]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 3556: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 3556 does not exist.
Apr  2 19:26:54 laptop gnome-shell[3386]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
```

The lag does not appear when entering password after screen lock. Is there any way to speed up the login process or trick GDM into logging in automatically but showing screen lock so that only the user with the credentials can access system.

With my limited understanding of DE and login managers, my research on the topic yielded only an old [Ubuntu wiki article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BetterLoginSpeed) which appears to have been [implemented](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/better-login-speed)

Comment: Something like this happened to me with Ubuntu 18.04, a long time ago.  I "put up with it" for 2 years and the problem "went away" when I upgraded to 20.04...  I never asked a question here since it was a server and rarely did I have to login locally.  Look forward to seeing what replies you get...

Comment: @Ray I can't imagine putting up with this for 2 years, you have a lot of patience! It's not that I'm complaining with a 7 second delay, I don't think I would mind an additional 7 seconds tacked on to the bootup time. The really grating part is the point at which the delay appears - enter password and then watch an empty purple screen for 7s with a laggy/stuck cursor.

Comment: Oh...  Since it was a server, I logged in only a few times per year locally (i.e., when there was a problem that couldn't be fixed remotely).  If this is a desktop machine and you have to put up with it on a daily basis, indeed, it would be annoying!  Since it's a fresh install, you could consider 21.04, when it's released...  I mean, only if no one else can give you a better solution.  I hate to suggest "upgrade!" to solve problems, but sometimes, that does work...  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A workaround solution that is less annoying. May not be best practice security wise.

1. Enable auto login
2. Create a unit file to start the lock screen after bootup: `/etc/systemd/system/lock_screen.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Lock screen after bootup since gdm login is slow
After=display-manager.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/sleep 5
ExecStart=/usr/bin/loginctl lock-sessions

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

3. Enable it: `systemctl enable lock_screen`
4. Reboot
5. If it doesn't work, increase the sleep time.